# BS4 Web-Scraping, my list comprehension only returns single result

Tags: python, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

I'm pretty new to Python and very new to web-scraping, I've searched thoroughly what could be wrong but am stuck.

As a learning project I want to scrape the current top 100 UK charts. I've got 4 lists to store results (position, title, artist, previous position).

To keep things tidy I've tried using list-comprehension to loop through the results - but only one result is returned each time (always the first) suggesting the loop isn't looping.

What's odd is this exact code has worked on a previous project on a different site?

I've checked the 'charts' variable by printing it and it definitely contains all the data needed so don't think that is the issue.

Here's what I have so far (eventually this will go in a pandas df but need to get the lists right first!)

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

charts = soup.find_all(class_='chart-positions')

# create our lists (Position, Title, Artist, Prev Postion)

cur_pos = [item.find(class_="position").get_text() for item in charts]
artist = [item.find(class_="artist").get_text() for item in charts]
title = [item.find(class_='title').get_text() for item in charts]

print(cur_pos)
print(artist)
print(title)
```

Any help or guidance in the right direction would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I looked at `https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart/` source and there is single element with `chart-positions` - namely `<table>`, if I am not mistaken single records are enclosed in `<div>`s with class `track`, so you should do:

```
charts = soup.find_all(class_="track")
```

You might do `len(charts)` to check if you have excepted number of items - with your code it give me `1`, after my change `100`. You would also need to adjust your code as there is no `position` class used. So far I can tell `artist` and `title` parts do work.

Comment: That's great, thank you. Hadn't considered using len() to check data, will do that in future - thanks again

Answer (score 0):

I never used BeautifulSoup, so I guess a proper solution could be more precise. However `find_all` could be a useful function in your case.

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

charts = soup.find_all(class_='chart-positions')

# create our lists (Position, Title, Artist, Prev Postion)

cur_pos = list(map(lambda x: x.get_text(),[item.find_all(class_="position") for item in charts][0]))
artist = list(map(lambda x: x.get_text(),[item.find_all(class_="artist") for item in charts][0]))
title = list(map(lambda x: x.get_text(),[item.find_all(class_="title") for item in charts][0]))

print(cur_pos)
print(artist)
print(title)
```

Outputs:

```
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5', '6', '7', '8', '9', '10', '11', '12', '13', '14', '15', '16', '17', '18', '19', '20', '21', '22', '23', '24', '25', '26', '27', '28', '29', '30', '31', '32', '33', '34', '35', '36', '37', '38', '39', '40', '41', '42', '43', '44', '45', '46', '47', '48', '49', '50', '51', '52', '53', '54', '55', '56', '57', '58', '59', '60', '61', '62', '63', '64', '65', '66', '67', '68', '69', '70', '71', '72', '73', '74', '75', '76', '77', '78', '79', '80', '81', '82', '83', '84', '85', '86', '87', '88', '89', '90', '91', '92', '93', '94', '95', '96', '97', '98', '99', '100']
['\nARIANA GRANDE\n', '\nMARIAH CAREY\n', '\nWHAM\n', '\nLITTLE MIX\n',
....
```

Comment: Thank you, there are some things in your solution that are new to me so very helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

### Problem(s) in original code

The issue originates with your use of `find_all` here:

```py
charts = soup.find_all(class_='chart-positions')
```

This returns a `list` containing a single element - there is only one element where `class="chart-positions"` in the HTTP response from the URL provided. So when you go to run:

```py
cur_pos = [item.find(class_="position").get_text() for item in charts]
artist = [item.find(class_="artist").get_text() for item in charts]
title = [item.find(class_='title').get_text() for item in charts]
```

Each list is being populated with a single `find` result for each `item` in `charts` - which as mentioned previously has only a single element.

### Simple solution

You could get around this to get the output in the format you are aiming for in your original question by implementing something like the below.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup

page = requests.get('https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

chart = soup.find(class_='chart-positions')

cur_pos = [item.get_text() for item in chart.find_all(class_='position')]
artist = [item.get_text() for item in chart.find_all(class_='artist')]
title = [item.get_text() for item in chart.find_all(class_='title')]
```

### Storing data

If you plan on running this script regularly and want to store chart data  extracted for future reference or analysis, the following example makes use of [`pandas`](https://pandas.pydata.org/) to store the data retrieved to a date named csv file - see also the use of the `get_text()` `strip` kwarg to remove leading and trailing whitespace from inner HTML text extracted.

```py
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime

page = requests.get('https://www.officialcharts.com/charts/singles-chart/')
soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

chart = soup.find(class_='chart-positions')

data = {
    'cur_pos': [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in chart.find_all(class_='position')],
    'artist': [item.get_text(strip=True) for item in chart.find_all(class_='artist')],
    'title' :[item.get_text(strip=True) for item in chart.find_all(class_='title')]
}

df = pd.DataFrame(data)
date = datetime.today().strftime('%Y-%m-%d')
df.to_csv(f'Charts_{date}.csv', index=False)
```